# Error using uic to convert .ui file to .py file in Python in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

i am getting this eror
Cannot start process, the working directory 'D:\python beg\ScriptsC:\Users\thaku\OneDrive\Desktop\proj' does not exist

Comment: Your WORKING DIRECTORY is pretty nice !!!

Comment: @proghb thanks             but can u help me to solve this problem

Comment: This means exactly what it says. No such directory. Where it is - i don't know. You did present nothing about your issue. Look at your directory that returns the error !!! It is C;\ and D:\ in the same path.